# Display a terminal window after login on a Live Lubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, lubuntu, login, autostart

I'm currently customizing a Live Lubuntu USB. I've added Autostart commands to rc.local and they run perfectly fine, however, I have a dd command that runs on Autostart as well that takes a lot of time. It doesn't display the terminal window after login so it's not possible to see the progress of dd.

The Autostart in the home directory is not an option because it's a Live OS. The user will be generated on boot.

Is there any other way to run the command after login of any user so that it displays the terminal?

Comment: Is a [*persistent* live system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) an option for you? In that case you can use 'Autostart'.